# can you use wireless charging on LG G3 s

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lg, nfc, wireless-charging, lg-g3-vigor

can you get wireless charging on the LG G3 s as under the cover on the back of the phone there are two pins that connect to the cover, this cover also has a pad on the back. Thanks.

Comment: This phone is also known as LG G3 vigor/mini

Answer (score 0):

Your phone doesn't support wireless charge, but you can try to find a cover which enables it: the cover connects to the micro usb of the phone and has an embedded coil (and some other hardware). I'm not sure it exists, but you can try to find it.